# YARN install works but NPM install fails

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have a package.json with the following contents. When I do an npm install , it does not work where as when I do yarn install it works fine.
I also have a `npmrc` file with `@sap:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` . These are the only two files in the folder. How YARN works differently than NPM here?

```
   {
    "name": "npm-yarn",  
    "dependencies": {
        "@sap/dwf-dws-client": "~2.6.0" 
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "^12 || ^14"
    } 
}
```

I get the following error using npm install.

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @sap/xssec@2.2.5 (sha512-hGE9+PFNqeW3U5tC0gbV4Fn1B69D2aWo3xPzQ9baVZkuG0a+yOaL+t6bwJetfTwdwmW5Pts9o2egGEQBW3I5Xg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-aMV30QoSZ5yaXDw1FbIhFuJ3Lq8= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-aMV30QoSZ5yaXDw1FbIhFuJ3Lq8= but got sha512-3fuRTVJq3FYNDbfzavMQFSuSb+n9T42zsqXMvqNPv3z/9+0h6zzAFX3W+Rr3Xn8agKCwgeBU7FDClOiaWB7IRg== sha1-wsWT8RsLAMyqF+/wRTc5Lr3aEbQ=. (20614 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely related but I got a similar error when configuring a local npm repository (I used verdaccio, but there are others). My `npmrc` file contains: `registry=http://localhost:4873`

In my case, the command `npm cache verify` solved the issue. The output is something like:

```
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache)
Content verified: 2951 (283951575 bytes)
Content garbage-collected: 29 (9498096 bytes)
Index entries: 2951
Finished in 6.017s
```

Hope it is somewhat useful.